# Managing WIFI Connectivity on Startup

Tags: android

I have an application where the first thing it does is connect over wifi and make an http request to get a welcome message.  The application is set to start on Powerup.  So I want to make this rebust. I know how to check if wifi is established yet, but if I find that it is not yet there.  How do I delay and repeat attempt to connect?  Not sure the right way to introduce the delay.  Also Is there some other message besides powerup that I should be catching which occurs after all WIFI established?
Or some delay on powerup that I could use?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Just check the return code or exception from your http request. If it fails, then wait some reasonable amount of time then try again.

You did not mention what OS you use, seems to be Windows. If so, there are APIs to check the status of network interface, but do not use that. It is less reliable than simply checking the result of real work request.

Answer (score 0):

You don't say which broadcast message you are responding to, but you should be listening for BOOT_COMPLETED.

If WiFi is unavailable, then just use AlarmManager to wake up your service/app after a while and retry your communication. You could also use CountDownTimer, but this may block so may not be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check the WiFiState on PowerUp
2. If it is OFF, register a BroadcastReceiver for the android.net.wifi.WIFI_STATE_CHANGED intent.

When the WiFi is turned ON, the onReceive of your BroadcastReceiver will be called. Check the WiFiManager [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WifiManager.html) for more info.